# Classification of special Hopf algebras

Tags: representation-theory, hopf-algebras

Is there a classifications of (connected+ finite-dimensional) algebras A that are Hopf algebras with indecomposable projective modules $P_1,...,P_n$, such that every algebra of the form $B=End_A( P_1^{m_1} \oplus ... \oplus P_n^{m_n})$ (which is morita equivalent to A) is also a Hopf algebra as long as one $m_i=1$?

Comment: The paper Green-Solberg: Basic Hopf algebras and quantum groups gives a result which quivers can occur. If by "quiver algebra" you mean without relation, then there is a necessary and sufficient condition in Cibils-Rosso: Algèbres des chemins quantiques.

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer But quivers without relations are never Hopf algebras expect for the field (assuming finite dimensional algebras).

Comment: The paper by Cibils-Rosso considers also path algebras of infinite quivers.

Comment: By the way, I would be sceptical that there is an algebra $A$ such that every algebra $B$ Morita equivalent to $A$ has a Hopf algebra structure. Have you checked whether this holds for $A=k$ even?

Comment: As a Hopf algebra needs to have a $1$-dimensional module, no finite dimensional algebra can have the property that every Morita equivalent algebra has a Hopf algebra structure.

Comment: Thats a good point, I modified the question so that it hopefully makes more sense.